# org-mode: archiving to gpg-encrypted file

Tags: org-mode

My org mode file is gpg encrypted.

I've been able to setup transparent decryption when opening the file and encryption when saving to disk.

**However**, archiving an entry still puts it into unencrypted "_archive" file.

Setting manually `org-archive-location` unforotunately doesn't work:

> Emacs won't archive an entry to a previously encrypted file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me with Org version 9.1.14 in Emacs version 25.3.50 (actually Aquamacs 3.5 on a Mac). I made a GPG-encrypted Org file in `/tmp/nt.org.gpg`:

```
#+ARCHIVE: /tmp/nt.org_archive.gpg::

** my headline
** headline to archive
   with some text
```

It seems to be the case that Org is unhappy creating the archive file, but that it is happy to use it if it exists. So be sure to create the archive file first.

Comment: Works exactly as you described! Thank you! For future note: you need to put the ARCHIVE line exactly as it is above, including every space, otherwise won't work.